# How to loop client's socket reader

Tags: java, sockets

This is my simple client-server app.My server works fine, it's looped and it reads input of client each time client connects and writes anything.But I don't know how to loop `reader` in client code, so I can frequently write messages to server without manual reconnecting.(I tried to put code into `while(true){}` loop but it didn't work.Also if there's anything wrong with my simple server, I appreciate any help.Thanks!

Client code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.Socket;

public class client{

  private Socket client;
  private String text;
  private PrintWriter writer;
  private BufferedReader reader;

public void connectToServer()throws IOException
{

      client=new Socket("localhost",63400);
      reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
      writer=new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(),true);

      text=reader.readLine();
      writer.println(text);
}

public static void main(String args[])throws IOException
{
  client instance=new client();
  instance.connectToServer();
}
}
```

Server code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class server{

   private ServerSocket server;
   private Socket client;
   private BufferedReader reader;
   private String text;


public void startServer()throws IOException{
    server=new ServerSocket(63400);

    while(true)
    {
      client=server.accept();
      reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
      text=reader.readLine();
      System.out.println(text);
    }
}

public static void main(String args[])throws IOException{
    server instance=new server();
    instance.startServer();
}
}
```

Comment: Well as you suggest in the title, how to loop, requires a loop, I see none in your client's implementation. Would be better to show us your code when it had the loop on the client side.

Comment: there have lots of example on client-server communication using java socket